# Start a process 'as administrator' is not working

Tags: c#, windows

I am using the following code within a program that does not have elevated privileges

```
ProcessStartInfo pInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        pInfo.FileName = fileToExcecute;
        pInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        pInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
        pInfo.RedirectStandardError = false;
        pInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        if (runAsAdministrator)
          pInfo.Verb = "runas";

        Process p = Process.Start(pInfo);
```

The end user is asked to select whether they wish to run the program in elevated mode or not. **The above however is not starting the program 'As Administrator' when runAsAdministrator is true**. I have ran the 'fileToExcute' manually 'As Administrator' and it prompts to make changes to the computer.

I then added a manifest to the 'fileToExecute' to run with elevated privileges every time and when running that program directly I am properly prompted to confirm permission to make changes to the computer. **When I run the above program that uses the above code, I get:**

```
    System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005):
 The requested operation requires elevation at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
    at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo) at
    #HLg.#ic.#zNg(String #ANg) in #pOg:line 135
```

I really want the first option to work. I've tried everything and can't work out why the first option is not working.

Answer (score 4):

You can't combine the `Verb` property with `UseShellExecute = false`, since verbs rely on that functionality. Set `UseShellExecute` to `true` and it should work.

Comment: Thank you. I found this very frustrating :-(

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code and did not use the pInfo configuration options. I just changed everything to p.verb = "runas" etc and it is now working.